# source bin/activate not updating prompt: Is my virtualenv really active? If not, how can this be fixed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, zsh

I am trying to run virtualenv for the first time and when I run the following code the shell prompt does not change.

```
$ virtualenv test
New python executable in test/bin/python
Installing setuptools............done.
$ source test/bin/activate
$
```

I'm assuming it did not activate my environment because there is no `(test)$` prompt. The `virtualenv` command creates the directory correctly, so the activate file is there, it just seems to not be working?

I have tried this command as well and it gives the same result.

```
$ . test/bin/activate
$
```

Is my virtual environment running and I just cannot see the prompt(and is there something I can run to check that)?

or

Is my virtual environment simply not running and I am not activating it correctly?

I'm using Python 3.6.0(installed from Homebrew), virtualenv 15.1.0, Mac OS X 10.11.6, and zsh(oh-my-zsh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the help from Charles, I discovered it was my oh-my-zsh theme(powerlevel9k) that was just not displaying the prompt. I simply needed to add in the `virtualenv` Python Segment in my `~/.zshrc` described  [here](https://github.com/bhilburn/powerlevel9k#customizing-prompt-segments).

Comment: If you get a chance, could you edit the pertinent content into the answer? Otherwise, the answer could become less useful if the link breaks. (See also the analogy talking about how a sign telling the reader where to get apples is not an apple, at [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) on [meta.se]; likewise, a link to an answer is not an answer itself).

Answer (score 4):

To tell if your virtualenv is active without depending on the prompt (which shell configuration can override in persistent ways), use:

```
declare -p VIRTUAL_ENV
```

If the output is:

```
declare: no such variable: VIRTUAL_ENV
```

...then your virtualenv is genuinely not active. By contrast, if the output is:

```
typeset -x VIRTUAL_ENV=/Users/jess/test
```

...then it's active, but your prompt has been overridden.

---

To diagnose this (either the failure to activate, or the prompt override not sticking) in zsh, use:

```
PS4=':%x:%I+'  # the equivalent to this in bash would be PS4=':$BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO+'
set -x
source test/bin/activate
```

...which will print source file, line number, and command executed for everything done both during *and after* the `activate` script is sourced; this should include the activate script updating your PS1 (or, potentially deciding for some reason not to execute); and may include a function hook changing your PS1 back to a version that doesn't have the prompt updated to show the virtualenv's state.

Comment: Thank you! It is running because I am getting `typeset -x VIRTUAL_ENV=/Users/jess/test` so it must be getting overridden (I'm thinking in my .zshrc or my .bashrc). Any suggestion on how to get the prompt to display?

Comment: I'd want to see the output of running with `set -x` (and the PS4 given above) before I could suggest something. Make sure when collecting that log, by the way, that you're starting in an originally-deactivated state. (If you wouldn't mind, by the way -- I'd appreciate it if you chose an *ad-free* pastebin to post that on; https://gist.github.com/ is a good one).

Comment: Ah maybe it's an oh-my-zsh theme I'm using. Here are the results. https://gist.github.com/yieldjessyield/6774269ec40664640f51bc61013ad7fa#file-file-output-running-with-set-x

Comment: Agreed -- looks like the theme to me too.

Comment: ...googling around a bit, it looks like using [the virtualenv plugin for oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/plugins/virtualenv/virtualenv.plugin.zsh) might be the thing to do -- though as I don't use zsh myself (used to over a decade ago, but found myself learning bad habits that bit me when writing code for other shells), not in a position to test.

Comment: Thanks, Charles I'll poke around the theme some to get the prompt showing. Appreciate the help.

Comment: NP. I'd appreciate an upvote if the answer helped you -- once you figure out how to make oh-my-zsh play nice, you can either add your own answer with that solution (accepting your own answers is perfectly acceptable and appropriate when they include information not available elsewhere), or let me know how it works out to edit that solution into my answer. Either way, once something that actually fixes the problem for you is in an answer, clicking the checkbox next to that answer will mark your problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using oh-my-zsh on iterm and want to prompt virtual environment then ,
Do `open ~/.zshrc` Add/update virtualenv in that file like this `POWERLEVEL9K_LEFT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS=(context time battery dir vcs virtualenv custom_wifi_signal)` Then finaly don't lforget to `source ~/.zshrc`